# Dealing with pointers that may not point to anything

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I have a set of objects in a vector of pointers to their baseclass held inside a manager:

```
std::vector<object*> objectVec;
```

Classes may wish to spawn one of these objects using the Add() method in the manager. The problem is that they then subsequently need to set or update these objects themselves. I've decided to have Add() return a pointer to the object itself, which is stored in whatever class has decided to spawn one. The problem is dealing with the case where the object behind that pointer may have been deleted.

Add looks like this:

```
object* ObjectManager::Add(object* obj)
{
   objectVec.push_back(obj);
   return objectVec.back();
}
```

and used like this:

```
objectptr = ObjectManager::OMan()->Add(new object());
```

Where objectptr is a member of whatever class has called the function. So should that particular object be deleted, the pointer returned by Add would point to rubbish.

Is it my responsibility to ensure that whateverclass::objectptr is always set to NULL if this object is deleted? Or can this be dealt with using some sort of smart pointer? The problem being that I don't need to use a smart pointer to deal with the possibility of a memory leak, but to deal with the case where the stored pointer has become invalid.

Please let me know if i've been unclear, or if the question is badly formed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might want to revise your design altogether. You shouldn't need neither base class for all objects nor any manager thingy for them. Especially if it's going to be a singleton. Also use pointers when you absolutely need them, and cannot do with values and references.

Comment: The baseclass is in this case specifically for a type of object that has subtypes (lights), i've just generalised it to an object class for the question. My problem is needing access an object stored in a manager for setting values quickly, which rules out iterating through a vector until I find it by ID. I am entirely open to other suggestions!

Comment: @jgf: Other suggestions include "pointing to the desired object directly".  Isn't dereferencing a pointer the fastest look-up operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely want weak_ptr and shared_ptr. shared_ptr is a general smart pointer class.  weak_ptr is an observer of shared_ptr.  When all the references of the shared_ptr go away, instances of weak_ptr "become null" and are easier to deal with than a pointer to a deleted object.

These classes come with Boost.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.htm

And if I'm not mistaken, there are equivalents built into std namespace on compilers that implement newer C++0x standards.  Visual C++ keeps has this built in.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/02/16/10128357.aspx

Oh shoot, looks like everyone else beat me to the answer...

Comment: A weak_ptr observing shared_ptrs is exactly what i'm looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can store smart ptr's instead of raw ptr's in your vector. In this case if somebody releases an object, it's not deleted until the last reference is not released (the one held in vector in your case). You can use `boost::shared_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` (C++11).

If this is not what you want, you can use `boost::weak_ptr` to store references in your vector. `weak_ptr` doesn't increment reference counter so if somebody releases an object, it's get deleted, but reference (weak_ptr) stored in your vector allows you to check this.

Answer (score 2):

Best is to forget this "manager" idea, but if you do or if you don't, the solution to shared ownership is the same as always, use `boost::shared_ptr`.

Or, with relatively new compiler, use `std::shared_ptr`.

Considering that with `shared_ptr` the ownership issue is taken care of already, then ask yourself, what is it that the "manager" manages?

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: In this case, it's Lights - which needs to be drawn to a specific buffer, and with specific blending settings - so it's convenient for them to be centralised.

Comment: @jgf: don't forget this "central" object manager idea is just a fancy way of organizing (or a fancy syntax for) global variables.  Global state always makes it harder to test applications and verify correctness, as functions relying on that state yield different results at different times.  Global variables are never *really* convenient.  They just *seem* so at first.

Comment: I'm intending to completely rewrite this program after i've had an attempt at implementing the various features i'm after, as i've read similar things to what you've mentioned, so the question was generalised a bit, as really i'm just after the best way to deal with dangling pointers that need to be set to NULL!

Comment: @jgf: in this case, the need to set pointers to `0` is a symptom of your design, hence Alf's recommendation.  The structure of your application causes you to allocate memory using `new` and manage pointers although it can probably avoid it.  Consider writing a proper copy constructor for your `Light` class and storing the different "light" instances as `std::vector<Light>`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it my responsibility to ensure that `whateverclass::objectptr` is always set to `NULL` if this object is deleted?

You're writing the class, so it's up to you to decide.  This is a design decision and either choice is admissible, provided that you **document** it:

1. design the application
2. write the documentation/specification
3. write the code to matches the specification

> Or can this be dealt with using some sort of smart pointer?

Using a smart pointer (strong or weak version) will help achieve whatever behavior you chose for the class.  However, it will also strongly affect the client code.  In the following code:

```
class Scene
{
      // can't use this object in a call to `ObjectManager::Add()`,
      // assuming it uses a smart pointer to deal with object lifetimes.
    Object myLight;
};
```

The use cases for the `ObjectManager` class should be taken into consideration, on top of simplicity of implementation.  Think "write once, use a lot".

Answer (score 0):

Dangling pointers and memory leaks are two different issues, but a proper shared pointer can protect from both.  For this particular case, I'd suggest `boost::shared_ptr`.

Use `std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<BaseType>>` for the vector type and also have the objects that hold the bare pointers now hold instead a `boost::shared_ptr<BaseType>`.  This will ensure that the pointers will stay valid in the `vector` and in the objects as long as one of those objects still exist.

If you have differing requirements, you can use a `boost::weak_ptr` in one of the places holding the pointer (either the `vector` or the object).

Also, the object can hold a derived type instead of a base type (`boost::shared_ptr<DerivedType>`) and you can convert between them using `boost::shared_static_cast`.

[Here is the documentation for all of these concepts.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm)

Comment: Hit the enter key a little early?

Comment: My proxy flaked out, and when it came back only part of my answer was saved :(